# Why Is My Method Not Pushing Results to My Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, this

I've created a simple object. I'm trying to create a method on the object that manipulates the data from one array and pushes the data to two new arrays. For some reason, the new data will not populate the two new arrays. When I run the method john.tipCalc(); nothing is pushed to my empty arrays.

```
let john = {
  fullName: "John Smith",
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips : [],
  finalBill : [],
  tipCalc: function() {
     this.bills.forEach(function(bill) {
       let percentage;
       if (bill < 50) {
          percentage = 0.2;
       } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
          percentage = 0.15;
       } else {
          percentage = 0.1;
       }
      this.tips = bill * percentage;
      this.finalBill = bill + bill * percentage;
    });
  }
};
```

I'm wanting the 'tips' array to populate with the tip which is calculated in the tipCalc method as bill * percentage. Then I want the 'finalBill' array to populate with the bill total plus the percentage tipped which is calculated with bill + bill * percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `push()` into `tips`. You will also need to use an arrow function `() => {}` in the `forEach` if you want to use `this.tips`  the way you are:

```js
let john = {
    fullName: "John Smith",
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tips : [],
    finalBill : 0,                  // shouldn't this be a single number?
    tipCalc: function() {
       this.bills.forEach(bill => { // use arrow function
         let percentage;
         if (bill < 50) {
            percentage = 0.2;
         } else if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 200) {
            percentage = 0.15;
         } else {
            percentage = 0.1;
         }
        this.tips.push(bill * percentage);    // push()!
        this.finalBill +=  bill * percentage; // add
      });
    }
  };

 john.tipCalc()
 console.log("Tips", john.tips)
 console.log("Final:", john.finalBill )
```

If for some reason you can't use arrow functions, you can pass `this` as the final parameter to `forEach()`

Comment: Thank you! I had tried .push but it kept telling me that tips wasn't defined. Can you explain why the arrow function makes it work?

Comment: @SamuelStokes, that's actually a really big, and hard explain topic in javascript. Basically `this` is set by context of the function call. When you call `john.tipCalc` this gets set to the `john` object. But the callback to `forEach` is an anonymous function called by forEach so it has a different context and this doesn't get set to `john`. Arrow functions take `this` from the local scope just like any other variable. There are literally books about it. The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is probably as good a place to start as any.

Comment: Thank you! I have actually seen what you are talking about before, but since my understanding is still limited I often forget things like this. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Array.push() :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Correction :

```
this.tips.push(bill * percentage);
this.finalBill.push(bill + bill * percentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
this.tips = bill * percentage;
this.finalBill = bill + bill * percentage;
```

You are overwritting the arrays with the result of that operation.

You *need* to push them:

```
this.tips.push(bill * percentage);
this.finalBill.push(bill + bill * percentage);
```